# HTML Table's columns scrolling

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an html table inside a Div and here is the screenshot
[image]

the table is in a `<div></div>` right now with `overflow x` and `y` `:auto`
but in this way it scrolls the whole table 
what i want to do is to fix the `Sheet1` column and allow other columns to scroll how can i do this ?

Here is a demo jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8aaZZ/ in this fiddle i want to make  `Fields` column fixed and `Records` columns to be scrolled horizontally..

Comment: Would be easier to help if you could reproduce the issue in jsfiddle.net or alike.

Comment: Please post your markup and CSS, and also consider putting together a jsFiddle which replicates the issue.

Comment: well that could be hell of a mess coz this table is being populated via mvc, but i will try to make a js fiddle according to this scenario ..

Comment: @BenM i have added a demo fiddle, plz see the updated question

Comment: @AdilWaqar, your demo does not scroll for me?

Comment: i didn't added the div because i don't want to scroll the whole table ,

Comment: i want to fix the first column of table and scroll the remaining columns horizontally ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by giving `position:absolute` to first column you can achieve the effect.

HERE is a **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yigurugi/2/edit)**.

```
.table-data
{
  background:#f6f6f6;
  overflow-x:scroll;  
  overflow-y:visible;
  margin-left:5em; 
  width: 60%; 
}

table{border-collapse:separate; table-layout:fixed;}

table th td{padding:5px;  width:100px;}
table td{border:1px solid gray;}

table td:not(:first-child)
{background:#f6f6f6;overflow-x:scroll;  }

table td:not(:first-child):hover
{background:red;overflow-x:scroll;}

table td:first-child, table th:first-child{ 
  position:absolute; 
  width:5em;
  left:0;
  top:auto;
  background:cyan;
}
```